# Time complexity of Special Double For-Loop?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

So I was just asked this question in an exam, and it's driving me crazy. The question is this:
What is the time complexity for the following code in terms of n:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < n; j = j * 2) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

a) O(n log(n))

b) O(n^2)

I firmly believe the answer to be n(log(n)), because the inner loop only runs k times, where k^2 <= n, which is only log2(n), for which the time complexity is log(n). However, everyone I have talked to who was also in the exam thinks the answer to be n^2. Can anyone give me a firm reasoning for either way? Thank you!

Comment: You've got that backwards. `k^2 != n`, rather `2^k = n` `nlogn` looks accurate to me. That being said, it's extremely easy to test. Run this code and print `count` at the end with some test values.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct with minor edit below about the answer as `O(n log n)`. There is no way the answer can be `O(n^2)`.

`2^k = n` so `k = log n`

The inner loop will run: `log n` times
The outer loop will run: `n` times

So this is `O(n log n)` time complexity